# PHP - Sqlite Search From Keywords In CSV - Displaying First Result Only

Tags: php, sqlite, csv

I am trying to implement a feature where a user can add "keywords" into a csv file, then the PHP code will loop through the keywords to find matches using the "LIKE" function.

```
$row2 = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row2: <br /></p>\n";
        $row2++;

        echo "<table id='example1' class='table table-bordered table-hover dataTable' role='grid'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th aria-controls='example1' aria-sort='ascending'> FilePath </th>";
        echo "<th> HashValue </th>";
        echo "<th> NameNoPath </th>";
        echo "<th> FileExtension </th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo "1";
            echo "Data is:" . $data[$c] . '<br><br>';
            //$data[$c] = $tst;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `hash` WHERE `HashValue` LIKE '$data[$c]' ";
            echo $sql;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if ($result) {
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "TEST";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row2['Filename'] . '<br>';
                    echo "<td>" . $row2['HashValue'] . '<br>';
                    echo "<td>" . $row2['NameNoPath'] . '<br>';
                    echo "<td>" . $row2['FileExtension'] . '<br>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                echo "2";
            }
                //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
fclose($handle);
}
```

The code works for the FIRST record it matches only.
I have narrowed down the issue to the `while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` loop. All test "echos" work perfectly up until that point.
Why is that while loop not executing correctly?

Comment: Note that you never have a closing `</tr>` tag in your loop

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. Unfortunately, doesnt fix the issue

Comment: You need to put it after this line :  `echo "<td>" . $row2['FileExtension'] . '<br>';`

Comment: You also don't have closing `</td>` tags either.  Not that it will fix the problem, just another problem

Comment: Have made the changes in my code, just havent updated the code above :)